# Spring Security http filter chain's not working

Tags: spring-security

I think this config ( the http filter chain)  is not being aplied because I need everyone can acces the "/" but it requests authentication in any case and if you're logged in u can access any url, so it also ignores the rol configs. It's an api rest, and I see the login page if I write the url on browser, maybe I have to dissable default spring boot config but I don't know how.

````
/* La clase tiene esta anotación*/ 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/pedido").hasRole("CLIENTE")
        .antMatchers("/crear-producto").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
        

    return http.build();
        
    }```
````

Comment: Please, use only English in all parts of the question (title, problem description).

Comment: *"if you're logged in u can access any url, so it also ignores the rol configs"* - that means that an authenticated user without required role can access end-points `/pedido` and `/crear-producto`? Can you provide screenshots from the client you're using?